# How can I render a proper normal pass for smoke in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I would like to render a normal pass for smoke in Cycles like this one:

[image]

I'm aware of [this method mentioned in Blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?351534-Smoke-Domain-Box-not-welcome-in-Normal-pass-e-Z-Depth-pass!) but the result is far from the result needed to relight in post (via Normal Node or After Effects' Normality plugin).